# CSS background images aren't loading

Tags: css, background, loading

My question is why aren't my background images loading on my website (in my CSS file)?  I have set them as !important, which doesn't work.  I have also tried the images locally, which still doesn't work.  Is it a problem if the images are currently hosted on a different URL? Thanks.

Comment: Without any code, no one will ever know

Comment: Have you looked at your web page from a developper tool such as FireBug ?

Comment: Sorry, I had my own code, but take this duplicate runescape page for example.  www.etheriata.com.  CSS: http://etheriata.com/resources/global-74.css

Comment: Are the paths to the images correct?

Comment: @user1760134 what do you expect us to do with that CSS file? Go through it all and look for the code? StackOverflow isn't some sort of On-Demand service where you go to demand for help. You need to put some effort into your question so we can (and are willing) to put some effort into answering it. We need code, http://jsfiddle.net demos and maybe some screenshots so we can hopefully solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You are linking to images on the `http://www.runescape.com/` domain and they are responding with `404 Not Found`, even though the images do exist if you browse to them directly (i.e they respond with `200 OK`). This means they have [disabled hotlinking](http://techgyo.com/index.php/disable-hotlinkingprevent-sites-stealing-bandwidth-htaccess-trick/).

You're trying to use others resources, but regardless of that, this is why the images aren't loading when being used by your domain because they have disallowed it.

Solution: Use your own images, placed in a location you have control of.

Answer (score 0):

1. If your trying to use someone elses image, maybe they do not allowed hot linking.
2. If your image is stored locally or in your own server validate the path or url maybe its wrong.

Comment: Think it must be 1. as the URLs being used do exist and respond, but 404 when the request is made from www.etheriata.com

Answer (score 0):

There's definitely not enough information to answer well... but if you're talking about your #Background element, it's probably a pathing issue.  Make sure your path is set correctly.

```
#Background{
 background: url(background_simple.jpg) no-repeat center 65px black;
 width: 100%;
 min-width: 1000px;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
}
```

For example, if your CSS is in your /resources/ directory, and your image is in an /images/ directory, then what you're using won't work.  You'd need something like:

```
background: url(../images/background_simple.jpg) no-repeat center 65px black;
```